# pointer array to structure in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, structure

```
int noOfEmployee = 0;
cout << "Enter no. of Employee" << endl;
cin >> noOfEmployee;

Ereg = new EMPLOYEE[noOfEmployee];

string defaultName = "Emloyee";

for(int i = 0; i < noOfEmployee; i++) {
    Ereg->regno = i + 1;
    Ereg->name = defaultName;
}

for(int i = 0; i < noOfEmployee; i++) {
    cout << Ereg->regno << "\t"
         << Ereg->name << endl;
}

delete [] Ereg; //segmentation Fault if [] missed
```

output is:

```
Enter no. of employee
5
5    Employee
5    Employee
5    Employee
5    Employee
```

How could access array elements in this or do something like this

```
Ereg[i]->regno = i;
Ereg[i]->name = defaultName;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for help,

There is one way of doing this i got just now.

As incrementing a structure pointer will move it towards next structure location so I used basic method.

```
(Ereg + i)->regno = i;
(Ereg + i)->name = defaultname;
```

And it worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

`Ereg` points to the 1st element of array, so `Ereg->regno` or `Ereg->name` will always access the 1st element.

> How could access array elements

You should

```
for(int i = 0; i < noOfEmployee; i++) {
    Ereg[i].regno = i + 1;
    Ereg[i].name = defaultName;
}

for(int i = 0; i < noOfEmployee; i++) {
    cout << Ereg[i].regno << "\t"
         << Ereg[i].name << endl;
}
```

See [subscript operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_subscript_operator).

BTW

> //segmentation Fault if [] missed

You should use `delete[]` for array `new[]`d (and use `delete` for pointer `new`d).

Answer (score 1):

Your output repeats itself because you never use `Ereg` as an array, only as a pointer to `EMPLOYEE`.

> How could access array elememts in this or do something like this
>
> ```
> Ereg[i]->regno = i;
> Ereg[i]->name = defaultName;
> ```

Use `.` instead of `->`, because `Ereg[i]` is a `struct`, not a pointer to `struct`.

> ```
> //segmentation Fault if [] missed
> ```

This is expected. You need `[]` because you allocated an array. Hence, `delete[]` must be used to avoid undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This is some kind of fun....

Also I can do this to use as a array.

As we know

```
*(Ereg + i) = Ereg[i]
// this is how array works, so I can write this

(Ereg + i) as (&Erg[i])
```

And this also worked fine.